# Grunt Jasmine "Cannot call method “join” of undefined"

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

Just upgraded to grunt-contrib-jasmine 0.6.0 with grunt 0.4.1.

The tests used to work but now I'm getting:

```
Running "jasmine:app2JsTests" (jasmine) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined Use --force to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs` is incompatible with the newest version of `grunt-contrib-jasmine` [as they have documented here.](https://github.com/cloudchen/grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs#conflict-with-grunt-contrib-jasmine-06x)